# How to hide an image only for Outlook

Tags: email, templates, outlook

I've built an HTML Email template which looks really good on most of the email clients but Outlook. It just doesn't want to read any inline CSS for images. Is there are way to hide images just for Outlook? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this around the image:

`<!--[if !mso]><!--> <img> <!--<![endif]-->`

I encourage you to post your html email so we could take a look and maybe suggest a solution.